# Change default tab of media manager

Tags: media, media-library, media-settings

Is there a way to change the default media manager tab? I have managed to remove everything that I didn't want to show in media manager, using the instructions from the first post here [Add a menu item to Wordpress 3.5 Media Manager](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76980/add-a-menu-item-to-wordpress-3-5-media-manager/). I also have created a custom tab.

The problem is that when I click the Add Media button in posts, it sends me to the Media Library by default, which I have disabled.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3oLk.png]

Is it possible to set the default screen from Media Library (which I have disabled) to the Insert from URL? So every time i click the Add Media I will get this screen:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH71z.png] (the one from Insert from URL).

My coding skills are nearly zero... and the closest solution to my problem I believe it's this [Changing the media library default tab](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74422/changing-the-media-library-default-tab), but it doesn't work...

Comment: Please explain _why_ the provided solution does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function rearrange_media_tabs($_default_tabs) {
    $_default_tabs = array(
        'custom' => __('Your Tab Name'),
        'type_url' => __('From URL')
    );

   return $_default_tabs;
}

add_filter( 'media_upload_tabs', 'rearrange_media_tabs' );
```

From the Codex: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_upload_tabs/

Comment: Could you add a little explanation on to why this answers the particular question and how it works?